# Error in allocation when multiplying two triangular matrix

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, allocation

I am trying to multiply one upper triangular matrix with two lower triangular matrixes and place the result in an upper triangular matrix. But I get a Segmentation Fault 11.

the matrixes are all of dimension (N,N).

Here is my code :

```
void momentLegendre(Image img){
    double sum;
    int i,j,p,q;
    for(p=0; p<=img.N; p++){ 
        for(q=0; q<=img.N-p; q++){
            sum=0.0;
            for(i=0; i<=p; i++){
                for(j=0; j<=q; j++){
                    sum+=img.momentsCN[i][j]*img.a[p][i]*img.a[q][j];
                }
            }
            img.legendre[p][q]=img.C[p][q]*sum;

        }
    }
}
```

Image :

```
typedef struct structureImage Image;
struct structureImage{

    int N;
    double **momentsCN; 
    double **a;
    double **C; 
    double **legendre;
```

main function :

```
 imgTest.momentsCN=allocation(N,N);
 momentCN(imgTest);
 imgTest.C=allocation(N,N);
 coeffCpq(imgTest);
 imgTest.legendre=allocation(N,N);
 momentLegendre(imgTest);
 for(i=0; i<=N; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=N; j++)
        {
            printf("%lf     ", imgTest.legendre[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

}
```

I have a result for all matrixes but Legendre.

I don't where the error might come from but I allocated a 2D array dimension (N,N) for all matrixes.

Comment: `<=` -----> `<` You are accessing you matrix out of bounds

Comment: You have to show _at least_ the definition of `Image` and all allocations, a complete MCVE would be even better.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve].

Comment: oh sorry. I edited it. Is that better ?

Comment: Still not complete: read here what a [MCVE] is.